# Pasting text into input boxes behaves incorrectly

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking-questions, internet-explorer-7, paste

On the "Ask Question" page, the Title input box initially contains "What's your programming question? Be descriptive." in grey text. Typing text erases the prompt and displays what you type in black text.

However, *pasting* text into the input box doesn't trigger the erase, inserts the pasted text into the prompt, leaves the text grey, and typing any further text doesn't trigger the erase either.

The same thing happens on other input boxes that contain initial grey prompts.

Browser: IE 7.0.5730.13

Update: This appears to be an IE-specific problem. I wasn't able to repro it in Firefox or Safari.

Comment: It's probably a keyup event.

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36872/javascript-bug-in-stackoverflow-title-for-new-question

Comment: Not a duplicate, that question doesn't say anything about *paste*, which is where the bug happens.

Comment: ah, IE only issues continue to impress. :)

Answer (score 1):

Feel free to upvote this so the community user will stop bumping the question.

Comment: The community user is *supposed* to keep bumping the question ("This is by design") because the question hasn't yet received an answer considered helpful. :-)

Comment: @Shree Because it's been [status-completed], this type of post is typical procedure here on Meta.

Comment: Oh I see... I didn't notice the tag, and the answers and comments didn't give that impression.

Answer (score 0):

> This is by design -- the help text
>   disappears when you begin typing.
>
> The title field had to be handled a
>   bit differently because it typically
>   has focus when the page loads.
>
> I think this might actually be a
>   behavior we want to extend to the tags
>   field, since the help text
>   disappearing on focus is not exactly
>   helpful when you, y'know, need help
>   entering text on that field.. the one
>   you just tabbed into.

[Jeff Atwood♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36872/javascript-bug-in-stackoverflow-title-for-new-question/36987#36987)

Comment: Yes, the field works correctly when *typing*. The difference is *pasting* text, where it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: @Greg, don't argue with me, argue with The Big Cheese ♦ himself.