# Cannot paste question title using Internet Explorer

Tags: bug, asking-questions, internet-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pasting text into input boxes behaves incorrectly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37119/pasting-text-into-input-boxes-behaves-incorrectly)

### Scenario

1. Click Ask Question button.
2. Paste something into the title.

### Expected Results

- Pasted text shows up in black
- Moving focus to question body prompts search for duplicates

### Actual Results

- Pasted text shows up in gray (like the default text)
- Moving focus to question body does *not* trigger search for duplicates

### Other notes

- Hitting submit gives error that no title was entered
- If text is typed manually there doesn't seem to be any problem, only an initial paste breaks it
- After the paste, manually editing the title doesn't cause it to be accepted either

Tested on IE8 on WinXP.

Comment: Solution: use a real browser

Comment: @squillman: I could quit my job, yes, but I don't know that being able to paste question titles in is worth *quite* that much to me.

Comment: I reported the same problem yesterday: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37119/pasting-text-into-input-boxes-behaves-incorrectly

Comment: The problem is you are using windows. Use a mac!

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Pollyanna, I do see this on IE7 even when I am logged in. The gray default text does not disappear from the text box, either.

Answer (score -1):

I confirm that this also occurs on IE7 when I am NOT logged in.  The default text "What's your programming question? Be descriptive." does not disappear, and clicking in the ask a question box doesn't preview possible duplicates.

However, after logging in, the Ask Question page appears to work normally.